# Kendo UI Dynamically Change Datasource String (XML)

Tags: jquery, xml, datasource, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Grid that binds to an XML DataSource. How can I have the DataSource change, based off the selection of a drop down list. Example:

```
//Create DataSource
    var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({            
        transport: {
             read: [DropDownListValue] + ".xml",
             dataType: "xml"
        }
         });

    gridDataSource.read();

    function createGrid(){                  
            var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: gridDataSource
                }...
             };
```

Where [DropDownListValue] is a drop down list on my form. In this example if [DropDownListValue] = 1, the datasource would be "1.xml". If [DropDownListValue] = 2, then datasource would be "2.xml".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by adding the following to the On Change event of my Drop Down list:

```
//Assign drop down value to variable
var dropDownListValue = $("#dropDown1").val();

//Concatenate drop down variable to file name
var dynamicUrl = dropDownListValue +".xml";

//Assign grid to variable
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

//Set url property of the grid data source
grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url =dynamicUrl;

//Read data source to update
grid.dataSource.read();
```

Comment: RegDwight, thanks for the cleanup. If you agree this is correct, please mark as answered. I can attest I am using it now and it works great.

Comment: How to send the property also ?