# Passing url to read as a parameter in kendoui datasource

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-ui

Let's say I have this kind of simple dataSource:

```
var TasksSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({

     transport: {
         read: {
          url: 'some url',
          dataType: "json"
        }
    }
});
```

And I want to use it several times, but with different urls. I couldn't find anywhere how to pass this to dataSource. And I don't want to use global variable. I was trying with custom methods, like for example `setUrl: function() .. etc` but eventually it didn't work

Comment: why wouldn't a function work? did you receive any errors?

Comment: when I was trying to use "TaskSource.setUrl('test')" it showed "Object [object Object] has no method 'setUrl' "

Comment: btw that method won't work as you didn't define a function in the datasource, so `setURL` wouldn't have existed. The way you have it written above instead just would execute the script inside of your function when it first defines your DataSource.

Comment: but i defined it in my dataSource..

Comment: you had a function inside of your datasource but that doesn't mean it is an extension of the datasource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you create the DataSource, set the url value like this:

```
TasksSource.transport.options.read.url = "Test";
```

Comment: Well generally you can navigate JSON formatted data with a dot notation, which first led me to think it was `TasksSource.transport.read.url`, but when that didn't work I was able to adjust my search a bit and came upon [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254334/kendo-ui-dynamically-change-datasource-string-xml) that did something comparable, and found that I was missing `options`.

Comment: well one thing isn't working. When I'm fetching the data ( via fetch function ) data isn't changing. So even though the source is different, data is still the same. Why is that?