# Kendo Scheduler: dynamically change resources datasource transport read

Tags: c#, javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

I'm using the resources in the kendo scheduler like:

```
group: {
  resources: ["Rooms"]
},
  resources: [
{
  name:"Rooms",
  title: "Room",
  field: "RoomID",
  dataSource: {
    autoSync: true,
    transport:
    {
    read: { url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Filter_Rooms", "Room", new{
                                    pFilter = false,
                                    pCapacity = 25,
                                    pBeamer = true,
                                    pTelevision = false
                                         }))",dataType: "json" }
                            }
                    }
},
```

Now I want to filter the resources according to users' input. So I've tried using javascript:

```
$("#btnFilter").click(function () {
 if (chkBeamer.checked){
      pbeamer = true;
      sessionStorage
     }
 else {
      pbeamer = false;
     }
 var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
 scheduler.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = Room/Filter_Rooms/true/25/false";
 scheduler.dataSource.read();
});
```

Goal: to change the **parameters** in the **resources datasource transport read** of the scheduler. In order to filter the **resources** **dynamically** and update the scheduler with the resources or rooms who are conform to the filter.

I've seen this in this post: 
[Kendo UI Dynamically Change Datasource String (XML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254334/kendo-ui-dynamically-change-datasource-string-xml)

But when I try to use this for my case it's not working and error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed). The resource cannot be found.

I'm using this function to filter in my controller (it works just fine hard coded...)

```
public ActionResult Filter_Rooms(bool pFilter, int pCapacity, bool pBeamer, bool Television)
  {
  using (var sampleDB = db)
      {
      if (pFilter){
      IQueryable<RoomViewModel> rooms = sampleDB.Spaces.ToList().Where(r => r.roomCapacity == pCapacity && r.roomBeamer == pBeamer && r.roomCapacity == 25 && r.roomTelevision == false).ToList().Select(room => new RoomViewModel(){
                      roomID = room.Id,
                      text = room.roomName,
                      color = room.roomColor,
                      value = room.Id
                  }).AsQueryable();
                    return Json(rooms.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
      else{
      IQueryable<RoomViewModel> rooms = sampleDB.Spaces.ToList().Select(room => new RoomViewModel(){
                    roomID = room.Id,
                    text = room.roomName,
                    link = "google.be",
                    color = room.roomColor,
                    value = room.Id
                  }).AsQueryable();
                    return Json(rooms.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
             }
}
```

}

So how can I change these parameters dynamically to filter the resources of my scheduler?

Comment: You cannot write the read url as you have created, if you have not changed the routing rules. So your read URL would be like **`Room/Filter_Rooms/?pFilter=true&pCapacity=25&pBeamer=false&pFilter=false`**. Also your question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23913367/net-kendo-scheduler-dynamically-change-datasource-resources